# Are 0's allowed in OID arcs?

Tags: asn.1, hl7-v3, hl7-cda

Can 2.16.840.1.113883.3.2966.**0**.1 potentially be a valid Object Identifier (OID)? A colleague told me that zeros aren't allowed in arcs after the first, however I can't find any documentation on that. A reference to a definitive specification would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a zero value in arc is totally allowed. I don't know why your colleague said it isn't. See an [ISO 2022 Character Set Switching standard](https://www.alvestrand.no/objectid/1.0.2022.0.html) which has zero-valued arc in the middle and in the end

And here is a binary encoding (in hex) of your provided OID:

```
06 0C 60 86 48 01  86 F9 5B 03 97 16 00 01
```

it is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 3):

Zero arcs in OIDs are definitely allowed.  Valid OIDs values are governed by the Rec. ITU-T X.660 and X.670 series of recommendations and ISO/IEC 9834 series of international standards. Indeed if the first arc is 1 (iso) and second arc is 0 (standard), the third arc should be the number of the International Standard published by ISO or IEC.  You can also refer to http://oid-info.com for more information on Object Identifiers.